# SQL Group by query - needs your attention

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in a sql query. I have data like:

```
IdentityId  ProductId   TypeId   Rating
3           1             1      9
7           1             2      3
9           500           1      7
2           500           2      5
8           777           4      5
12          777           3      8
11          999           4      1
```

I need to the maximum Rating of each Product + i need the typeId associated with that Rating.

So the Product 1 have the maximum Rating 9 & the TypeId associated is 1

Product 500 have the maximum Rating 7 & the TypeId associated is 1

Product 777 have the maximum Rating 8 & the TypeId associated is 3

Product 999 have the maximum Rating 1 & the TypeId associated is 4

**like below output:**

```
ProductId   TypeId   Rating
1           1        9
500         1        7
777         3        8
999         4        1
```

Please ask me if the question is not clear.

Thanks for your valuable time & help.

Comment: The question _could_ be ambiguous. Can we assume you mean "for each type ID, get the product ID and rating from the row with the highest rating for that type"?

Comment: are you expecting the same result , i think there is some mistake please confirm

Comment: @paxdiablo: I tried my best to exaplain it. I am sorry if it is not CLEAR.
I need DISTINCT Products Having the maximum Rating, but i also need the TypeId of the Rating.

Comment: The requested output was clear to me Yaqub. I think what you want is the Product IDs with the highest rating, regardless of TypeId. Is that right? The solutions below help you do that.

Comment: yes, but i also need the TypeId of the Rating.

Comment: @Yaqub Ahmad check out the below query , may help you.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad: that's okay, what you've said in the comment seems clear enough, but it doesn't match your expected results. The maximum rating for the distinct product 500 would come from `500 1 7` rather than what you have, `500 2 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  IdentityId int,
  ProductId int,
  TypeId int,
  Rating int
)

insert into @T values  
(3,           1,             1,      9),
(7,           1,             2,      3),
(9,           500,           1,      7),
(2,           500,           2,      5),
(2,           777,           4,      5),
(12,          777,           3,      8),
(2,           999,           4,      1)

;with C as
(
  select ProductId,
         TypeId,
         Rating,
         row_number() over(partition by ProductID 
                           order by Rating desc) as rn
  from @T
)
select ProductId,
       TypeId,
       Rating
from C
where rn = 1
order by ProductId
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
  Select [ProductID], [TypeID], [Rating] 
  from [tblTest] 
  WHERE [Rating] in 
  (
    SELECT MAX([Rating])
    from [test].[dbo].[tblTest]
    group by [TypeID] 
  )
```

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks. You are actually only getting the maximum Rating per Type.
I have updated my question, just to explain the output i require. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select *  from product where Rating in (
select max(Rating)  from product group by  ProductId )
```

and you will get the following result

```
1   1   9
500 1   7
```

Comment: The grouping needs to be on typeId, the result you posted here is not the result asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to have just one SQL like this

```
select *  
from product p1
where rating = (select max(Rating)  
                from product p2
                where p1.ProductId = p2.ProductId)
```

However this SQL can return mutiple results of the same product if your data has something like:

```
IdentityId  ProductId   TypeId   Rating
3           1             1      9
7           1             2      9  // note: same max rating
```

The result will show both rows.

If you really want to show just 1 row per product and you do not care which typeId will be shown. You can use this SQL instead.

```
select p1.productId, max(p1.typeId), max(Rating)  
from product p1
where rating = (select max(Rating)  
                from product p2
                where p1.ProductId = p2.ProductId)
group by p1.productId
```

You can change max(p1.typeId) to min(p1.typeId)

I hope this could be another alternative.

Comment: Tanchasoen: Thanks. I tired it but got an error:
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Yes, create the table which holds the data mentioned in my question (you can find the sql for it in the accepted answer) & try your provided sql.

Comment: Both SQLs work fine for me. Although, I have tested them on mysql, the SQLs should work with mssql as well.

Comment: Anyways, you may try to change 'rating=(select max(rating)' to 'rating in (select max(rating)'. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
select IdentityId, ProductId, max(Rating)  from TABLENAME group by ProductId
```

This seems to work, although I'm not sure how 'legal' it is to leave identity id off the group by clause.
(snap @ Bryan ;)

Comment: I make sure to always use WD40 on my keyboard for slightly faster typing :P

Comment: Column 'IdentityId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.